# Is there a shortcut to solving this probability problem?

Tags: probability

Assume that person A throws a dice and gets 1 point every time they get a six, this is repeated 12 times. Now we have person B that also throws dice and gets 1 point every time they get a five, this is repeated 10 times. Now, what is the probability that the sum of the points they have at the end is less than 5.

To solve this I drew a figure with 10*120=120 total possibilities then I drew where their sum were 4 or less and then calculated the proportion of the two areas.

$$ \frac{6}{120} = 0.05 $$ but this is way off the right answer of 0.7. No idea of how to get there though. Could you please help?

My other thought is to use Binomial distributions somehow but that sounds too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of success for each player is the same, i.e. $\frac16$.

As to whether they score with a six or a five makes no difference - they may as well score if either throws a one (or other number).

As to whether the first player takes all their turns first or not, or they alternate, or whatever, also makes no difference.

Therefore this is equivalent to one player throwing the die $22$ times and counting success as throwing a one.

Therefore the distribution is Binomial with $p=\frac16$ and $n=22$.

The required probability is $p(X\leq4)=0.7003568316...$ (by calculator)